# Who was Harold Finch's father?

Tags: person-of-interest

Is there any explanation of who was Harold Finch's father?

Based on feeds that machine presents in the series, they were living in a suburban home, remote from crowded locations or even other houses.

It looks like the father was retired, but not clear where he worked exactly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p415.jpg

Comment: Why is this important. What relevance does Harold's father's occupation have?

Comment: ^I haven't watch since the show aired, but his father does appear a couple of times. His name was Tom played by Tuck Milligan, I believe. I would presume the character plays a role on who Finch is--but I agree that the purpose of wanting to know this information should be apart of the Q, but there is some significance, because his relationship is what in part prompts him to build the machine...

Comment: @Paulie_D the reason Harold have started thinking about the Machine was that he wanted to create memory for his father, a friend that will watch over and protect him. This was (among other things of course) Harold's motivation and maybe even subconscious life purpose because he was not able to build a friend for his father and couldn't protect him. So it would be good to know, where Harold's tooling (like even hardware to create a prototype of a memory) and initial knowledge comes from. That is why I think it is important.

Comment: https://personofinterest.fandom.com/wiki/Harold_Finch%27s_Father

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> who was Harold Finch's father?

> father was retired, but not clear where he worked exactly

First name: Thomas

Surname: unconfirmed

> Occupation: Teacher

https://personofinterest.fandom.com/wiki/Harold_Finch%27s_Father

(Difficult to see, but Certificate of Death shows occupation as teacher)